# Visual Studio cannot find custom Attached Property in XAML file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I tried to put all my grievance in one picture:

[image: Visual Studio being a Diva]

As you can see the second and only the second Attached Property "DropHandler" makes VS throw the The attachable property '{0}' was not found in type '{1}' Exception. It is defined alongside the first Attached Property in the same source file in the exact same manner (unless I'm overlooking something obvious).

The error appears with the same property across different files and as you can see once more further down in the same file. It's also not the only AP where this is happening.

As soon as i close the XAML source file the error disappears and the project compiles fine even with the file open.

I'm using the latest official Build of VS 2017 - but this is happening in VS 2015 as well. This is not at all a development-blocking issue by all means but it irritates the heck out of me. I have to keep closing files i'd rather have open just to get that ugly error out of my sight.  If anyone knows how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Yes, I actually almost always clean-rebuild.
Cleaning by itself does not get rid of the error and building the assemblies one-by-one has no effect either.